# update&select in on transaction ,can't get the data

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, transactions, mybatis

background:
sprintboot + mysql5.7 + mybatis
repeatable read
i thought i can select the data which insert in one transcation.but the answer is no.

```
    @Transactionnal
    public void test(){
        dao.insert();//insert data 
        dao.select();//select data insert previous row.but can't find
    }
```

i tried command in mysql client, like this :

```
start transaction;
insert into ....
select * from ....
commit;
```

and the data insert can be found in select after insert;
i really can't understand why .

Comment: Why would you want to select what you have just inserted?

Comment: @serapme It should work. I would look into it if you could provide a small repro like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and share it on your GitHub repo. By the way, if your goal is to retrieve auto-generated keys, you should use `useGeneratedKeys` instead.